# Sets of Hausdorff measures zero

Tags: measure-theory, fractals

Let $H^g$ be the Hausdorff measure with respect to gauge function $g$.

I need to construct an example of a set E for which:

$H^g(E)=0$ for $g(r)=r^s$, $s>0$

and
$0<H^g(E)<+\infty$ for $g(r)=2^{-(log(1/r))^s}$ or $2^{-(1/r)^s}$